# java pattern to obtain the pagename with extension

Tags: java, regex

For the URL http://questions/ask/stackoverflow.xhtml, the requirement is obtain stackoverflow.
What is the pattern used to obtain this page name?
The substring can be used but I read that the performance for pattern Matcher would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular URL you can use:

```
String url = "http://questions/ask/stackoverflow.xhtml";
String pname = url.split("/")[4].split("\\.")[0];
```

For the more useful (in terms of regex not in performance) Pattern based solution consider this:

```
String url = "http://questions/ask/stackoverflow.xhtml";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("/(?![^/]*/)([^.]*)\\.");
Matcher matcher = pt.matcher(url);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched: [" + matcher.group(1) + ']');
    // prints Matched: [stackoverflow]
}
```

Comment: The url can be anything. But we have to find only the pagename. In this scenario stackoverflow

Comment: Then its better to use my Pattern based solution, that will work for any URL.

Comment: A **best** solution is to use the `URL` object, that will work for all the URLs that the regex isn't taking into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that a regular expression solution would be more complicated (and likely slower).  Here's how I would do it without them:

```
public static String getFilename(String s) {
  int lastSlash = s.lastIndexOf("/");
  if (lastSlash < 0) return null;
  int nextDot = s.indexOf(".", lastSlash);
  return s.substring(lastSlash+1, (nextDot<0) ? s.length() : nextDot);
}

String url = "http://questions/ask/stackoverflow.xhtml";
getFilename(url); // => "stackoverflow"
```

Of course, if the URL doesn't have a filename then you'll get the hostname instead.  You're probably best off parsing a [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), extracting the file part of it, and removing the path and extension.  Something like this:

```
public static String getFilename2(String s) {
  URL url = null;
  try {
    url = new URL(s);
  } catch (MalformedURLException mue) { return null; }
  String filePart = url.getFile();
  if (filePart.equals("")) return "";
  File f = new File(filePart);
  String filename = f.getName();
  int lastDot = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
  return (lastDot<0) ? filename : filename.substring(0, lastDot);
}
```

Comment: using the `URL` object is the most correct way to do this, it is going to handle **any** properly formed URL correctly, some ad-hoc regex is going to break on some input somewhere.